# Pass parameters in post http request

Tags: java, api, rest

I want to pass variables in Java Rest API
The Post URL is :
***ex:*** https://localhost:8080/webresources/test?id=.....

**This is my current code:**

```
@POST
@Path("test")    
public String newRequest() throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {
        ...
 }
```

How should I pass my parameter to call my request like this : **newRequest(123)**;

Answer (score 0):

You want to add [@QueryParam](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) for query parameters, as:

```
public String newRequest(@QueryParam("id") String request_sf_id) throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException { ..}
```

> Binds the value(s) of a HTTP query parameter to a resource method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property.

Comment: @ POST
    @ Path("newrequest")    
    public String newRequest(@ QueryParam String request_sf_id) throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException { ..}       Like this ??

Comment: @nicoletannous updated similar endpoint which get id query parameter with your String variable name

Comment: But I am not working on Spring framework to use RequestParam/QueryParam

Comment: @nicoletannous my solution is without spring framework

Comment: `@Path` is imported from same package as `@QueryParam` so you should have this solution available

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequestParam:

```
@POST
@Path("test")    
public String newRequest(@RequestParam(value ="id") String id) throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {
        ...
 }
```

And calling :

```
https://localhost:8080/webresources/test?id=.....
```

Please note, RequestParam is part of spring so you need :

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
```

Comment: RequestParam should be imported or should I add a jar file to be able to use it ?

Comment: You are assuming OP has Spring

Comment: @user7294900 , you are correct. let me edit my answer

Comment: @nicoletannous , fine, then you can refer other answer posted for non spring based solution.

Answer (score 0):

@POST
@Path("newrequest")
public String newRequest(**@HeaderParam(**"request_sf_id") String request_sf_id) throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {
...
}

**This is my answer.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).